# preg_replace on part of database query

Tags: wordpress, preg-replace

I suppose it'll be a piece of cake for an expert ... me already pulling my hair off.
OK, I have to perform preg_replace on a chunk of WordPress' "posts_where" query. Here's the original piece:

```
$where = " AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%lorem%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%lorem%')*INSERTION*)) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')"
```

Please note that *INSERTION* above, the only thing I gotta do is to insert another OR condition/clause.
Is there a way to do it with preg_replace? Or else? Something like:

```
$where = preg_replace( "REGEX", $my_INSERTION_stuff, $where );
```

Thanks a bunch!

**EDIT**

Anybody willing to resolve the problem for a prize? It's really important!

Answer (score 0):

You do not even need preg_replace for this, just use str_replace:

```
$where = str_replace( "*INSERTION*", $my_INSERTION_stuff, $where );
```

Comment: I think I don' get it, sorry.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry - I misunderstood you.

Comment: *INSERTION* represents the exact position of where new stuff needs to be inserted, it doesn't exist in that (written) form at all. Sorry if not being clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I have realized how simple it might be! Hopefully it helps someone.

```
$where = preg_replace("/(AND.*?\))(\)\))/", "$1{$insertion}))", $where, 1);
```